# 1734: The array bounds are invalid

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a script in which I need to run one command as an administrator. When I ran this command the script errors with a 1734 error.

My script is very basic:

```
runas /user:Administrator "myexec.exe \"param with spaces\" otherparam -Djava.ext.dirs=%JAVA_EXT_DIRS%"
```

The problem comes from the variable JAVA_EXT_DIRS which is kind of huge.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but I've ran into the same problem on Windows 10 with the runas command now. It turns out there's a maximum length for the *program* parameter, which has to be below 995 characters.

For example, this command still works:

```
runas /user:someuser /savecreds "cmd.exe 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"
```

The *program* parameter here has 994 characters, and it should open a new command prompt. But if you add one more 1 within that parameter, the execution will fail with a `1734: The array bounds are invalid.` error.

And if you increase the the *program* parameter even further to 1026 characters, the error changes to `-2147024809: The parameter is incorrect.`.

The regular limit for command line parameters seems to be much much larger (I've read something about 8191 characters here on SO), so this seems to be a problem with runas.exe itself.

---

**Edit:**
I even ran into a similar problem when I tried to use a PowerShell script with the `-Credential` flag like this:

```bsh
$username       = "username" 
$password       = "password"
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credentials    = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username, $securePassword
$argument       = $args[0]  

Start-Process -FilePath "C:\path\to\my.exe" -Credential $credentials -ArgumentList "-arg $argument"
```

So it's probably a problem with the underlying Windows mechanics and not runas.exe itself.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `%JAVA_EXT_DIRS%` may contain spaces too. You better put it in double quotes:

```
runas /user:Administrator "myexec.exe \"param with spaces\" otherparam -Djava.ext.dirs=\"%JAVA_EXT_DIRS%\""
```